# Getting val() from input

Tags: jquery, input

I've done this hundreds of times.. but I can't seem to get the following code below to work correctly. The appended text in the `body` is only showing as "/" (not display the values from the inputs).

HTML:

```
<input id="email" placeholder="email"/>
<input id="password" placeholder="password"/>
<button>
Register
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();

$("button").click(function() {
    $('body').append(email + "/" + password);
});
```

Any help getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get values inside the click event

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $('body').append(email + "/" + password);
});
```

Comment: thanks! but why can't the vars be outside the function?

Comment: @user1661677 vars outside gives you empty values while your input is empty and still not updated .. when you make it inside click it will give you the updated values .. you can try this yourself by put value="this my email"   and value="this is my password" for html  it will print it in your way

Comment: I see. I'd have to do a .change() fucntion or something similar I'd assume. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="email" placeholder="email"/>
<input id="password" placeholder="password"/>
<div id="someid"></div>
<button class="myclass">
 Register
  </button>
<script>
$('.myclass').click(function(){
var email =$('#email').val();
 var password =$('#password').val();
 $('body').find('#someid').append(email + "/" + password);
 })
</script>
```